# protecting attributes using state_machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, ruby-on-rails-4, state-machine

I'm trying to protect updates to certain attributes using [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

I want to LOCK updates on certain attributes when the state is `completed`

But instead of firing on STATE `completed` it fires during the transition to completed as well... meaning before the state has finished, preventing the state entirely!

eg

```
  ## BLOCK CHANGES MADE IN COMPLETED OR FAILED STATE
  validate :lock_down_attributes_when_published, :if => Proc.new { |log| log.state?(:completed) }
```

or

```
  validate :lock_down_attributes_when_published, :if => Proc.new { |log| log.completed? }
```

with

```
  private

  def lock_down_attributes_when_published
    return unless completed?
    message = "must not change when #{state}"
    errors.add(:head_count, message) if head_count_changed?
    errors.add(:quiz_master_id, message) if quiz_master_id_changed?
    errors.add(:qm_fee, message) if qm_fee_pennies_changed?
    errors.add(:total_fee, message) if total_fee_pennies_changed?
  end
```

It's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the most elegant solution but you might throw on the dirty method state_changed? In combination it should give you the functionality you want.

```
Proc.new { |log| log.completed? && !log.state_changed? }
```

That way it will only fire if the completed state just changed.

or

```
validate :lock_down_attributes_when_published, :if => Proc.new { |log| log.completed? && !log.state_changed? }
```